# Vue update data prop whenever element clientWidth changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I'm currently setting a data prop called `w` to whatever the clientWidth is for an element that I have in my HTML. It looks like this within my mounted hook:

```
data() {
 return {
  w: 0,
 };
},
mounted() {
  this.w = this.$refs.timelineProgress.clientWidth;
},
```

This works fine for initially setting `this.w` width that element's clientWidth but what I'm trying to do now is change the value of `w` whenever the clientWidth changes. This is so I can get the width of the element and store it whenever it shrinks or grows based on a devices screen size or if a user shrinks a page or something like that.

Any help solving this is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can probably try using [`created`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#created) and [`unmounted`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#unmounted) method to attach a window resize event to your component.

```
created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeHandler);
}
unmounted() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeHandler);
}
methods: {
    resizeHandler() {
        this.w = this.$refs.timelineProgress.clientWidth;
    }
}
```

In the `resizeHandler` method you can also debounce the state updation to make it more performant.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider this as a potential solution and try it out

Answer (score 2):

To get reactive values based on something else changing in your app, use a computed value instead of `data`. Assuming your ref is referring to a vue component rendering a timeline of sorts:

```
computed:
  {
    w() {
      return this.$refs.timelineProgress.$el.clientWidth
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out

Comment: Turns out this gives an error: "Cannot read property of 'clientWidth' of undefined"
Does this make sense? I'm assuming it has to do with the lifecycle and being within a computed property?

Comment: I will investigate the errors and see if I can get this solution working!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your ref is referring to, but for my use case I'm referring to another component. I need to access its internal $el to get the actual DOM element and then it works fine. Maybe this answer doesn't work for non-component instances (which I'm assuming is the case since you're able to get clientWidth directly from this.$refs.timelineProgress).

Comment: Since the other answer gives you more control over debouncing (computed always runs whenever the properties it references change), no need to try and use this one.